# Window function not giving running total

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

In the following query:

```
SELECT
 d.date,
 d.location,
 d.population,
 v.new_vaccinations,
 SUM(CAST(v.new_vaccinations AS int)) OVER (PARTITION BY d.location) AS total_vaccinations
FROM
 CovidDeaths d
JOIN
 CovidVaccinations v
ON
 d.date = v.date
 AND
 d.location = v.location
WHERE  
 d.continent IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
 d.location,
 d.date
```

the window function is simply giving the total of each location as opposed to the running total according to the date.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want a "running total" you need an `ORDER BY` clause in your `OVER` clause. Otherwise the `SUM` will include all rows within the `PARTITION`. The [documentation includes an example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-using-the-over-clause).

Comment: @Larnu : Thank you. I tried this and it works, but I am still not able to comprehend why it works. I read the documentation, it says- "The ORDER BY clause specified in the OVER clause determines the logical order to which the SUM function is applied." But doesn't that just mean that only the order is affected? How can it give the running total?

Comment: See the documentation it links to, paying close attention to the default boundaries when one isn't specified: [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL) - ORDER BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#order-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a running cumulative total, either `RANGE` or `ROWS` window must be specified or implied in the `OVER`, and therefore **you also need to add an `ORDER BY`**. Otherwise the window is the full partition.

Once you specify `ORDER BY`, **the default implied window is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`**, which gives different results for non-unique orderings from `ROWS`.

**Given that `date` is probably not unique, you also want `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`.**

```sql
SELECT
 d.date,
 d.location,
 d.population,
 v.new_vaccinations,
 SUM(CAST(v.new_vaccinations AS int))
    OVER (PARTITION BY d.location ORDER BY d.date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS total_vaccinations
FROM
 CovidDeaths d
JOIN
 CovidVaccinations v
ON
 d.date = v.date
 AND
 d.location = v.location
WHERE  
 d.continent IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
 d.location,
 d.date
```