# How to use subtraction in running total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and it contains `CW` Cash withdrawals, `CD` cash deposits and `CHQ` Cheque Deposits.

[image]

I need to generate running total. When i get `CW` the total must be subtracted and remaining `CHQ` and `CD` it should add the running total.

When i use `sum(<colname>) over(order by colname asc)` the addition is working fine but when i get `CW` i need to subtract the total and there is the problem.

Can any one help me to have both addition and subtraction for running total?

I tried the below code but its not working for `CW` subtractions.

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by DOT asc) as RNO, DOT, TXN_TYPE, CHQ_NO, TXN_AMOUNT
case    when TXN_TYPE = 'CD' then sum(TXN_AMOUNT) over (order by DOT) 
        when TXN_TYPE = 'CQD' then sum(TXN_AMOUNT) over (order by DOT)
        --when TXN_TYPE = 'CW' then sum(TXN_AMOUNT) over (order by DOT) - sum(TXN_AMOUNT)  over (order by DOT)
        when TXN_TYPE = 'CW' then select (TXN_AMOUNT from TransactionMaster where 

        end
as running_total 
--into #TxnData
from TransactionMaster
where datediff(YY,dot,getdate()) <= 2 and acid = 4
group by DOT, TXN_TYPE, CHQ_NO, TXN_AMOUNT
```

When the TXN_TYPE is CW then the TXN_AMOUNT should be minus with the next row value i.e., the given table first row TXN_AMOUNT is 37385.00 which is CW so the next running TXN_AMOUNT minus TXN_AMOUNT i.e., 37385.00 minus 30948.00 and the result should be 6437 and later 6437 + 102381 because CD the result should be 108818. Finally the new col should show 37385.00 and next 6437 and later 108818. Hope i made my point clear.

Comment: so exactly does your query not to much senses which summ do you want to get, may some more data as text and a wanted result.

Comment: That GROUP BY clause indicates a misunderstanding from what I see. What exactly do you want as a resultset? Do you simply want every row exactly as it exists in your table along with a running "balance"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Window function not giving running total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67836844/window-function-not-giving-running-total)

Comment: Sample data and expected results (as text not images) would help immensely

Comment: It looks like you need to remove the `GROUP BY` and use `sum(TXN_AMOUNT) over (partition by TXN_TYPE order by DOT)` but hard to say for sure

Comment: Inside SUM you can have an expression.  It can be used to test the type of transaction.  You can perhaps use the amount or 0 to sum a specific transaction type or types.  Or if adding all types, you can negate the value for some types.  For example, SUM((CASE TXN_TYPE WHEN 'CW' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END) * TXN_AMOUNT).  So perhaps a CASE for negation with a corrected running total query.